# ¿Cómo eliminar un elemento en un objeto con typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Quisero saber si hay forma de eliminar un elemento en un objeto con typescript sin tener que usar un foreach o recorrer el arreglo.
Ejemplo

```
JsonObject = [
 {CodigoId: "1", DescripcionId: "1", ID: "6928fe6e-5bae-0a36-c3f8-f4cb58325b4b"},
 {CodigoId: "2", DescripcionId: "2", ID: "7896fe6e-5bae-0a36-c3f8-f4cb58325b4b"},
 {CodigoId: "3", DescripcionId: "3", ID: "2587fe6e-5bae-0a36-c3f8-f4cb58325b4b"}
]
```

Ahora probé usando

```
const del = {CodigoId: "1", DescripcionId: "1", ID: "6928fe6e-5bae-0a36-c3f8-f4cb58325b4b"}
delete JsonObject[del]
```

Pero el elemento no se borra.

Las formas que he visto en otros post son recorriendo el arreglo o generando un nuevo arreglo que excluya el objeto a eliminar, pero no encuentro una forma que se pueda aplicar sobre el arreglo ya existente.

Comment: Saludos. Para eliminar un elemento de un `array` debes saber cual es la posición/referencia del mismo, lo que estas haciendo es asumir que pasado un objeto idéntico el proceso que invocas hará todo lo necesario por encontrarlo conforme. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292278/how-do-i-remove-an-array-item-in-typescript

Comment: No se puede sabiendo únicamente el item a eliminar?

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Usando `remove` de `lodash` (mira en https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#remove)  puedes "lograr algo parecido"; más sin embargo, no hay algo así como lo planteas realizar, como tal debes indicar la posición del elemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a que dentro de tu objeto tienes un ID, es posible hacer lo que deseas, ya que puedes comparar si el objeto que tienes existe dentro y lo eliminas.
Utilizando un splice y dentro consigues el index del objeto haciendo loop por sus elementos y comparando el ID;

```js
let JsonObject = [
  { CodigoId: "1", DescripcionId: "1", ID: "6928fe6e-5bae-0a36-c3f8-f4cb58325b4b" },
  { CodigoId: "2", DescripcionId: "2", ID: "7896fe6e-5bae-0a36-c3f8-f4cb58325b4b" },
  { CodigoId: "3", DescripcionId: "3", ID: "2587fe6e-5bae-0a36-c3f8-f4cb58325b4b" }
]

const toDel = { CodigoId: "1", DescripcionId: "1", ID: "6928fe6e-5bae-0a36-c3f8-f4cb58325b4b" }

JsonObject.splice(
  JsonObject.find((item, index) => {
    if (item.ID == toDel.ID)
      return index
  }), 1
);
console.log(JsonObject);
```

Tendrás que usar un bucle para encontarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de `splice`

```js
JsonObject = [
 {CodigoId: "1", DescripcionId: "1", ID: "6928fe6e-5bae-0a36-c3f8-f4cb58325b4b"},
 {CodigoId: "2", DescripcionId: "2", ID: "7896fe6e-5bae-0a36-c3f8-f4cb58325b4b"},
 {CodigoId: "3", DescripcionId: "3", ID: "2587fe6e-5bae-0a36-c3f8-f4cb58325b4b"}
]
JsonObject.splice(1, 1) // posicion del elemento, cantidad de elementos a eliminar
console.log(JsonObject);
```

Puedes leer mas sobre este en: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice

Comment: Pero tendría que saber la posición y en este caso se el item a eliminar

Comment: como el item?, el id del Objecto, si es asi, puede hacer una busqueda rapida con 'filter'. se mas claro para poderte ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `array.filter()` para obtener solo los elementos que no coincidan con el que quieres eliminar, pero conservas el objeto original intacto.

Cuando usas `delete`, se borra el elemento, pero en su lugar queda `undefined`, por lo que la opción más adecuada es `array.splice()` y, en cualquiera de los dos casos, es necesario recorrer el arreglo para encontrar su posición:

```js
JsonObject = [
 {CodigoId: "1", DescripcionId: "1", ID: "6928fe6e-5bae-0a36-c3f8-f4cb58325b4b"},
 {CodigoId: "2", DescripcionId: "2", ID: "7896fe6e-5bae-0a36-c3f8-f4cb58325b4b"},
 {CodigoId: "3", DescripcionId: "3", ID: "2587fe6e-5bae-0a36-c3f8-f4cb58325b4b"}
];
const del = {CodigoId: "1", DescripcionId: "1", ID: "6928fe6e-5bae-0a36-c3f8-f4cb58325b4b"};

// Definir variable que tendrá la posición del elemento a borrar
let borrar = -1;
// Recorrer arreglo por elemento y posición
JsonObject.forEach((item, index) => {
  if(item.CodigoId == del.CodigoId) {
      // Si el elemento coincide, actualizar variable
      borrar = index;
      // No hay posibilidad de usar break para cancelar
      // En todo caso, si son muchos elementos, conviene mejor usar un ciclo for
  }
});

// Borrar el elemento si existe en el arreglo
if(borrar >= 0) {
    JsonObject.splice(borrar, 1);
}
console.log(JsonObject);
```